# How to pass winston logger object to Shared models in Loopback3

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, winston, loopback4, loopback3

I'm using Loopback3 and trying to log message for shared model that are outside of project folder.
My project folder structure looks like below

```
myproj\server\logger.js   // using winston logger here
myProj\common\models\     // I've couple of models here and able to use above logger
```

Also, I've few more models outside **myproj** folder (../../shared/models). Below is my **server\model-config.json**

```
"sources": [
  "loopback/common/models",
  "loopback/server/models",
  "../common/models",
  "../../shared/models",  // Shared models
  "./models"
],
```

And **Person** is in shared models folder. How can i pass logger object to this.

```
module.exports = function(Person){

Person.greet = async function(msg) {
    logger.info("received message: " + msg);  // How to get here above winston logger object ?
    console.log("received message: " + msg);
    return 'Greetings... ' + msg;
}

Person.remoteMethod('greet', {
      accepts: {arg: 'msg', type: 'string'},
      returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'string'}
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

It can be somewhat messy when you have your loopback models spread across multiple directories or even repositories. Its always a good practice to console common parts like logger, validation, utils etc from a static global reference, attached to loopback instance object. This loopback instance object is present as a reference to all its models. The way I would solve this problem is...

1. Add a new boot script in your loopback3 project and attach instance of `logger` class to loopback's `app` instance.

```
'use strict';

const { logger } = require("./logger");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.logger = logger;
};
```

2. Now wherever needed, you can simply access it from the `app` reference present on the model.

```
Person.greet = async function(msg) {
 Person.app.logger.info("received message: " + msg);
 return 'Greetings... ' + msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like below

in server\server.js

```
const {logger} = require("./logger");

app.start = function() {
return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    :
    :
    app.models.Person.logger = logger;   // Adding new property to Person model
  });
};
```

in **Person** model

```
Person.greet = async function(msg) {
 Person.logger.info("received message: " + msg); // using logger object like this
 this.logger.info("received message: " + msg);   // or like this      
 console.log("received message: " + msg);
 return 'Greetings... ' + msg;
}
```